# How to Validate Forms on Submit in Framework7

Tags: reactjs, html-framework-7

Say a user clicks submit before entering values into certain fields. How can I trigger validations on all of the inputs before the submit completes?

Typically, HTML5 validations are clever enough to trigger the validations when the button is clicked, but this doesn’t seem to be happening with Framework 7 forms. Here’s a simple example.

```
<List form>
  <ListInput type="email" validate errorMessage="Please enter a valid email" />
  <ListInput type="password" validate errorMessage="Please enter a value" required />
  <Button>Submit</Button>
</List>
```

I tried using refs to trigger blur, but I'm not sure how to get ahold of the input element that ListInput creates.

Answer (score 2):

**1. HTML5 validation**

To get right HTML5 validation you need to have html button of type `submit` on form.

So in your example you have to add type prop to framework7's `Button` component:

```
<Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
```

**2. Catch submit event and parse form**

To catch submit event on your form add `onSubmit` prop to framework7's `List` component.

Framework7 also has a form parsing helper method [`app.form.converToData`](https://framework7.io/docs/form.html#form-data-app-methods). To use it you will also have to add `name` props to `ListInput` components.

Putting it all together will look like that:

```
<List form onSubmit={(e)=>this.onLoginForm(e)}>
  <ListInput placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" validate errorMessage="Please enter a valid email" />
  <ListInput placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" validate errorMessage="Please enter a value" required />
  <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
</List>
```

Check working example in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/alimamed/orzep1x8/